# Flash message not displayed with redirect_to named_route_url in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

In one controller I have

```
flash.keep[:notice]= "Your password has been updated successfully."
redirect_to organisation_show_url
```

In application layouts file I have

```
<% if flash[:notice] %><div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div><% end %>
```

But no flash message is displayed on the organisation_show page, what did I do wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
redirect_to organisation_show_url, :notice => "Your password has been updated successfully."
```

In application layout

```
<% if notice %>
    <%= notice %>
<% end %>
```